# How Can I Proxy To Multiple Application Running in Tomcat via mod_proxy

Tags: apache2, tomcat6, apache, mod-proxy

I have 2 web applications running under Tomcat6.  Currently, I can access one of them via mod_proxy with the following config...

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
     ServerAdmin email@email.com
     ServerName staging.domain.com

     ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1
     ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I can access app1 via http://staging.domain.com/app1.  I also want to be able to access app2 the same way: http://staging.domain.com/app2.  I configured a second VirtualHost however, only the first one works.  Is this even possible, to proxy 2 web apps under a single domain?  If so, any hints, tips, tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, you're already pretty much doing it: just add extra ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse statements.

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
     ServerAdmin email@email.com
     ServerName staging.domain.com

     ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1
     ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1

     ProxyPass /app2 http://localhost:8080/app2
     ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://localhost:8080/app2

     ProxyPass /app3 http://localhost:8080/app3
     ProxyPassReverse /app3 http://localhost:8080/app3
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So close, I was. :o)  Thanks.